# Iterate Group_by across Dataframe in R

Tags: r, purrr, tidyeval

I'm trying to simplify a current piece of code in my script.

I want to group by each possible combination of two categorical variables and summarise a mean value of my explanatory variable.

Example using mpg database found in ggplot2;

```
library(tidyverse)

   mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, model) %>% summarise(mean = mean(hwy))
   mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, year) %>% summarise(mean = mean(hwy))
   mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>% summarise(mean = mean(hwy))
```

(this would continue until all combination of categorical variables - columns is done)

```
mpg %>% group_by(cyl, year) %>% summarise(mean = mean(hwy))
```

etc...

My actual database has hundreds of categorical variables so I would like to iterate the process in a for loop or using purrr for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `purrr` to select character and factor columns and then `combn()` to select all of the combinations.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map_lgl(mpg, ~ is.character(.) | is.factor(.))%>%
  names(.)[.]%>%
  combn(2, function(x) {mpg%>%group_by_at(x)%>%summarize(mean = mean(hwy))}, simplify = F)
```

Note, this can become messy as `choose(100,2)` evaluates to 4,950 combinations.

Comment: Thanks I intend to filter the list of data frames created based on certain factors e.g max mean value in dataframe to make it more manageable.